# Tag not converted as Topic

Tags: tag, topics

I am creating CaseFeed  with #MyTag on Case when a case is Created.
It's working fine when i am creating a case as a SytemAdmin, and when i click on #MyTag it'll open all comments related to that TAG.

But When i create Case logged in as a Parner Community user It's creating #MyTag, but when i click on #MyTag

it throws an
Error

"**Topic Not Available:** The topic you were trying to access could not be found. Another user may have deleted it, the topic may have been created without proper permissions, or a system error may have occurred."

What above error exactly meant?

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Partner Community user's profile has permission to assign topics.

You can do this in:

```
Setup > Profiles > [Profile Name] > System Permissions > Assign Topics
```

Comment: I am using "Partner Community User" profile and that profile default have the  Assign Topics, Create Topics permission,  


But still i am getting "Topic Not Available: The topic you were trying to access could not be found. .....topic may have been created without proper permissions......"


1.Manually(By typing in Post)  i can create #SomeTag in Partner Community User and it converts as Topic

2.But when I am using process builder to dynamically create Tag with one field of Case it won't work in Partner community user and works well as a  SystemAdmin user

Comment: If you check your topic record - `'SELECT Name, NetworkId FROM Topic WHERE Name = 'SomeTag'`, I suspect your `NetworkId` field will be blank.  This needs to be populated with your Community Network ID.  I'm not sure if this is something that can be done with Process Builder.